# Practical uses of nsICategoryManager?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm working on a profile switching addon and came across [nsICategoryManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICategoryManager).

I was wondering what is this? What are some practical uses for it?

I read the MDN article but can't think of any uses for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `nsICategoryManager` is to add entries (typically XPCOM components) to categories. The manager itself merely provides that registration mechanisms, how the categories are used depends entirely on the code that reads out the category entries. For example, there it the [`profile-after-change` category](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM/Receiving_startup_notifications) for components that need to be activated when Firefox starts up.

Most extensions should no longer be using `nsICategoryManager` explicitly, adding a category entry can be done with a line in `chrome.manifest`:

```
category profile-after-change MyComponent @foobar/mycomponent;1
```

This will call `nsICategoryManager.addCategoryEntry()` implicitly when the extension is activated.

**Edit**: Just out of curiosity, I decided to search for `nsCategoryCache` in the Firefox source code to see what other categories there are. Here the list:

- `"content-policy"` for [`nsIContentPolicy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentPolicy) instances.
- `"net-content-sniffers"` and `"content-sniffing-services"` for [`nsIContentSniffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIContentSniffer) instances.
- `"vacuum-participant"` for [`mozIStorageVacuumParticipant`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIStorageVacuumParticipant) instances.
- `"bookmark-observers"` for [`nsINavBookmarkObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsINavBookmarkObserver) instances.
- `"history-observers"` for [`nsINavHistoryObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsINavHistoryObserver) instances.
- `"idle-daily"` for observers managed by [`nsIIdleService`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIIdleService).

These are only the categories being cached and monitored for changes, the complete list is much longer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain so well. I think this is a bit complex for me to understand haha. Acutally could this be used to watch for a local file getting modified? Where could I find the complete list?

Comment: @Noitidart: Watching local files isn't something that Firefox code needs so I would be very surprised if it were implemented. Also, categories are simple things with a regular string as their name - no way to specify a file name there. As to the complete list: feel free to search the code. There is no documentation listing all categories in one place, you should never need to use most of them.

Comment: Ah ok thanks man! Can you please give a copy paste example I can use with nsICategoryManager (of course it wont use chrome.manifest) I just don't understand and feel this thing is so powerful

Comment: @Noitidart: No, I won't. I answered your question, there is even a documentation link with examples. The rest is up to you.

Comment: It's not copy paste to scratchpad though and I can't figure out how to piece this all togather. It's ok I wish people would help me out the way I help others. But you gave a lot of time already thanks I really appreciate it. (o but if you change your mind there is one thing I can get help with is that C++ dll firefox thing I still can't figure it out, everyone says theres so many examples but i cant dissect it and make it work for me)